# Kendo with ASP.Net MVC : Display data in editor template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have my template (in "EditorTemplates" folder) and I try to display value of my model.

To display in an input, I do :

```
<input type="text" name="MyValue" data-bind="value:MyValue" />
```

But what if I just want to display one of values with Kendo, without an input field ?

EDIT :

For example, in the pure javascript kendo usage (without MVC helpers), you could do that with templates :

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <p>
            #= myCustomVariable #
        </p>
    </script>
```

Or with algorithms:

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <ul>
        # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
            <li>#= data[i] #</li>
        # } #
        </ul>
    </script>
```

How can I do that with kendo MVC templates ?

Answer (score 1):

To display a value it is a similar concept to the input's.

Something like this:

```
 <span data-bind="text:yourValue"></span>
```

obviously you can change the html tag to your needs.

Comment: Thanks but do you know if it is possible to use it and display with algorithms ? like the #= MyValue # syntax for classic kendo template without MVC template system. See my first post edit for more informations.

Comment: will this be used purely for displaying information or will it also have editing features on it as well?

Comment: The both. I want purely display informations but I also want to use it for algorithms (for editing features).